# Instance of 'minified:p<dynamic>': type 'minified:p<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Tags: flutter, dart, web

the following error was raised when I build and publish my application using codemgic workflow.
I have tried to run my application locally, using flutter run -d chrome. It is working perfectly on my device.

Whenever I build and publish the application using codemagic, the following error appears on chrome console:
[image]

In my application I am using hive to store machine states, one of the states are selected filters stored as **List**
I think the error occurs (in published web application only) whenever I want to get the filters from Hive box.

following is the code used to retrieve and cast the box:

```
var boxFilters = _appBox.get(Strings.hiveFiltersSelected, defaultValue: []) as List;
List<String> filters = List<String>.from(boxFilters);
filters = boxFilters.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
```

Comment: Same issue with Hive